# Windows API Subclassing - Win Docs Example not Working

Tags: c++, winapi, subclassing

I am new to Windows Api and still learning the basics. In my project I encountered a problem that requires subclassing, so I decided to find a sample code, compile it, and see how it works in practice. I have found a relatively straightforward example at the Windows Docs webpage [How to Subclass a Combo Box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclass-a-combo-box). After creating a parent window and making a few tweaks for the code to compile, I managed to run it, but the program appears to behave as if no subclassing was done.

This is not the first time a sample code found on the webpage is not working. Am I missing something?

My WinMain routine:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

WNDCLASSEX wc = { 0 };
wc.lpszClassName = "MyClassName";
wc.hInstance = hInstance;
wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wc.lpfnWndProc = ToolbarWindowProc;
RegisterClassEx(&wc)

hwndMain = CreateWindow(
    "MyClassName",
    "Title",
    WS_POPUPWINDOW | WS_CAPTION,
    0,
    0,
    500,
    210,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    hInstance,
    NULL
);
ShowWindow(hwndMain, nCmdShow);
UpdateWindow(hwndMain);

MSG msg;
while (GetMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessageW(&msg);
}
return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: Where in that code do you think you're sub-classing a window?

Comment: since when can you do "sub-classing" in C ?

Comment: "This is not the first time a sample code found on the webpage is not working" didnt you write that you made "some tweaks" ? Did the example work before that tweaks? What did you change?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 The code did not work before those tweaks. For example, the function ToolbarWindowProc uses the macro CreateWindow which expects LPCSTR parameter, yet the example supplies it with LPCWSTR.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Since Windows was designed?

Comment: @user253751 interesting. Just to avoid a misunderstanding: not every question for clarification is about being snarky, some are also out of curiosity ;). I looked at the linked example and saw all code labeled as C++, so I removed the C tag, forgive me if that was wrong (and please correct)

Comment: @for: *All* code samples in the Windows API documentation are labeled "C++", even though the majority of them are C. Microsoft simply don't have a C template for their online documentation.

Comment: See [Subclassing Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview) and [Safer subclassing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031111-00/?p=41883).

Answer (score 0):

You need to know why we need to subclass controls.

> Subclassing an existing control is another way to create a custom
>   control. The subclass procedure can alter selected behaviors of the
>   control by processing those messages that affect the selected
>   behaviors. All other messages pass to the original window procedure
>   for the control. For example, an application can display a small
>   bitmap next to the text in a read-only, single-line edit control by
>   subclassing the control and processing the [WM_PAINT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-paint) message.

Refer: [Subclassing the Window Class of an Existing Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/user-controls-intro#subclassing-the-window-class-of-an-existing-control)

From the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclass-a-combo-box) you provide, it seems that you didn't follow the tutorial to learn how to subclass controls.

But now it seems that you need a complete example to learn.

So the first step is to use the official template, see the screensnap below:

[image: 1]

After creation, you can start with subclassing static control.

Add the following message event to the `WndProc` function.

```
case WM_CREATE:
       {
           hWndStatic = CreateWindowEx(0, L"Static", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT, 10, 130, 200, 40, hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_OWNERDRAWBUTTON, hInst, NULL);
           SetWindowSubclass(hWndStatic, &OwnerDrawButtonProc, IDC_OWNERDRAWBUTTON, 0);
        return TRUE;
    }
    break;
```

Finally, add the callback function of the subclass control.

```
TCHAR szText[] = _T("TestString");
LRESULT CALLBACK OwnerDrawButtonProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        RECT rc;
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
        SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(255, 0, 255));
        DrawText(hdc, szText, _tcslen(szText), &rc, DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        return 0;
    }
    case WM_NCDESTROY:
        RemoveWindowSubclass(hWnd, &OwnerDrawButtonProc, 1);
        break;
    }
    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Note: Don't forget to declare the newly created function

Complete example:

```
// Test_SetWindowSubclass.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Test_SetWindowSubclass.h"
#include <commctrl.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"Comctl32.lib")

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100
#define IDC_OWNERDRAWBUTTON 101

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name
HWND hWndStatic;
// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
LRESULT CALLBACK OwnerDrawButtonProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_TESTSETWINDOWSUBCLASS, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_TESTSETWINDOWSUBCLASS));

    MSG msg;

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_TESTSETWINDOWSUBCLASS));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_TESTSETWINDOWSUBCLASS);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

//
//   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
//
//   COMMENTS:
//
//        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
//        create and display the main program window.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE: Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
       {
           hWndStatic = CreateWindowEx(0, L"Static", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT, 10, 130, 200, 40, hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_OWNERDRAWBUTTON, hInst, NULL);
           SetWindowSubclass(hWndStatic, &OwnerDrawButtonProc, IDC_OWNERDRAWBUTTON, 0);
        return TRUE;
    }
    break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Parse the menu selections:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;

    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}

TCHAR szText[] = _T("TestString");
LRESULT CALLBACK OwnerDrawButtonProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        RECT rc;
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
        SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(255, 0, 255));
        DrawText(hdc, szText, _tcslen(szText), &rc, DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        return 0;
    }
    case WM_NCDESTROY:
        RemoveWindowSubclass(hWnd, &OwnerDrawButtonProc, 1);
        break;
    }
    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Debug:

[image: 2]

After you understand the process of subclassing controls, you can review the comment Remy gave you.

- [Safer subclass control.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031111-00/?p=41883)